# How to remove C3 observable rinex data?

Tags: gps

**I have convert rinex data version 3.04 to 2.11 rinex using gfzrnx**

```
gfzrnx -finp 1828322a.22O -fout 322a211.22O -vo 2 -rsot 40
```

**When i do checking quality data using teqc, the result is:**

```
! Error ! '322a211.22O': unable to recognize observable code= 'C3'
```

```
teqc: failure to read '    15    C1    C2    C3    C5    C6    C7    C8    L1    L2# / TYPES OF OBSERV' on line 72 of '322a211.22O'(invalid observation type) ... exiting
```

**How to remove / observations out C3?**